# Running blender gives me libIlmImf.so.6

Tags: software-installation, blender

I installed blender (`$sudo apt-get install blender`)
But when I run blender it gives me an error

```
$blender
blender: error while loading shared libraries: libIlmImf.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I also tried downloading blender dirrectly and actually doing a ./blender on the download works however I want it too interface with unity (3d game engine).

Anybody know how to solve this?

The output of lsb_release -a is

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial



$apt-cache policy blender
```

gives me

```
blender:
  Installed: 2.76.b+dfsg0-3build1
  Candidate: 2.76.b+dfsg0-3build1
  Version table:
 *** 2.76.b+dfsg0-3build1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

and 
    ldd blender
gives me

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffed016d000)
    libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007f853ed99000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f853eb7e000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f853e8d4000)
    libpython3.5m.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0 (0x00007f853e24d000)
    libGLEW.so.1.13 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.1.13 (0x00007f853dfc9000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f853dd86000)
    libopenal.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenal.so.1 (0x00007f853db16000)
    libfftw3.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3.so.3 (0x00007f853d717000)
    libjack.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjack.so.0 (0x00007f853d4ce000)
    libsndfile.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so.1 (0x00007f853d265000)
    libtiff.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5 (0x00007f853cff1000)
    libOpenImageIO.so.1.6 => /usr/lib/libOpenImageIO.so.1.6 (0x00007f853c43f000)
    libjpeg.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 (0x00007f853c1e6000)
    libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0 (0x00007f853bfcd000)
    libboost_system.so.1.58.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.58.0 (0x00007f853bdc9000)
    libboost_thread.so.1.58.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so.1.58.0 (0x00007f853bba3000)
    libboost_locale.so.1.58.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_locale.so.1.58.0 (0x00007f853b8ba000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f853b69d000)
    libHalf.so.12 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so.12 (0x00007f853b45a000)
    libIex-2_2.so.12 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIex-2_2.so.12 (0x00007f853b23b000)
    libIlmImf-2_2.so.22 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf-2_2.so.22 (0x00007f853ad6d000)
    libOpenColorIO.so.1 => /usr/lib/libOpenColorIO.so.1 (0x00007f853aa76000)
    libopenjpeg.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenjpeg.so.5 (0x00007f853a852000)
    libavformat-ffmpeg.so.56 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavformat-ffmpeg.so.56 (0x00007f853a455000)
    libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56 (0x00007f853902b000)
    libavutil-ffmpeg.so.54 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavutil-ffmpeg.so.54 (0x00007f8538dbb000)
    libavdevice-ffmpeg.so.56 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavdevice-ffmpeg.so.56 (0x00007f8538b8d000)
    libswscale-ffmpeg.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswscale-ffmpeg.so.3 (0x00007f85388fe000)
    libjemalloc.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so.1 (0x00007f85386c6000)
    libspnav.so.0 => /usr/lib/libspnav.so.0 (0x00007f85384c2000)
    libGLU.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1 (0x00007f8538253000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/nvidia-361/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f8537fc3000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f8537c89000)
    libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f8537a79000)
    libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007f8537872000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f853766e000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f85372a5000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f8536f9b000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f8536c19000)
    libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007f85369f7000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f85367e0000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f85365b7000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f85363b4000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f85361ab000)
    libFLAC.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libFLAC.so.8 (0x00007f8535f36000)
    libvorbisenc.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2 (0x00007f8535c8c000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f8535a6a000)
    libjbig.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjbig.so.0 (0x00007f853585c000)
    libboost_regex.so.1.58.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so.1.58.0 (0x00007f8535553000)
    libopencv_highgui.so.2.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4 (0x00007f85352bd000)
    libwebp.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so.5 (0x00007f8535061000)
    libgif.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgif.so.7 (0x00007f8534e57000)
    libraw_r.so.15 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libraw_r.so.15 (0x00007f8534b97000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000556992aa5000)
    libicui18n.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.55 (0x00007f8534734000)
    libicuuc.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55 (0x00007f85343a0000)
    libIlmThread-2_2.so.12 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread-2_2.so.12 (0x00007f8534198000)
    libtinyxml.so.2.6.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinyxml.so.2.6.2 (0x00007f8533f82000)
    libyaml-cpp.so.0.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libyaml-cpp.so.0.3 (0x00007f8533d12000)
    libssh-gcrypt.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh-gcrypt.so.4 (0x00007f8533ac8000)
    librtmp.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1 (0x00007f85338ac000)
    libmodplug.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmodplug.so.1 (0x00007f8533521000)
    libgme.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgme.so.0 (0x00007f85332d2000)
    libbluray.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbluray.so.1 (0x00007f8533089000)
    libgnutls.so.30 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x00007f8532d58000)
    libbz2.so.1.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0 (0x00007f8532b47000)
    libswresample-ffmpeg.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswresample-ffmpeg.so.1 (0x00007f853292b000)
    libva.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libva.so.1 (0x00007f853270f000)
    libzvbi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzvbi.so.0 (0x00007f8532483000)
    libxvidcore.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxvidcore.so.4 (0x00007f853216f000)
    libx265.so.79 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx265.so.79 (0x00007f8531550000)
    libx264.so.148 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx264.so.148 (0x00007f85311ab000)
    libwavpack.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwavpack.so.1 (0x00007f8530f82000)
    libvpx.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvpx.so.3 (0x00007f8530b5e000)
    libvorbis.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0 (0x00007f8530931000)
    libtwolame.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtwolame.so.0 (0x00007f853070e000)
    libtheoraenc.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtheoraenc.so.1 (0x00007f85304cf000)
    libtheoradec.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtheoradec.so.1 (0x00007f85302b4000)
    libspeex.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libspeex.so.1 (0x00007f853009b000)
    libsnappy.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsnappy.so.1 (0x00007f852fe93000)
    libshine.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libshine.so.3 (0x00007f852fc85000)
    libschroedinger-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libschroedinger-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f852f9b0000)
    libopus.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopus.so.0 (0x00007f852f766000)
    libmp3lame.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmp3lame.so.0 (0x00007f852f4f0000)
    libgsm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsm.so.1 (0x00007f852f2e2000)
    libcrystalhd.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrystalhd.so.3 (0x00007f852f0c7000)
    libavfilter-ffmpeg.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavfilter-ffmpeg.so.5 (0x00007f852ed23000)
    libXv.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXv.so.1 (0x00007f852eb1e000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f852e90b000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f852e6e9000)
    libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007f852e4e5000)
    libxcb-xfixes.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-xfixes.so.0 (0x00007f852e2dc000)
    libxcb-shape.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shape.so.0 (0x00007f852e0d8000)
    libcdio_paranoia.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcdio_paranoia.so.1 (0x00007f852ded0000)
    libcdio_cdda.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcdio_cdda.so.1 (0x00007f852dcc7000)
    libasound.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2 (0x00007f852d9c7000)
    libSDL-1.2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0 (0x00007f852d72e000)
    libdc1394.so.22 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdc1394.so.22 (0x00007f852d4b7000)
    libpulse.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0 (0x00007f852d268000)
    libcaca.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcaca.so.0 (0x00007f852cf9f000)
    libraw1394.so.11 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libraw1394.so.11 (0x00007f852cd8f000)
    libavc1394.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavc1394.so.0 (0x00007f852cb8a000)
    librom1394.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librom1394.so.0 (0x00007f852c985000)
    libiec61883.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libiec61883.so.0 (0x00007f852c777000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/nvidia-361/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007f852c545000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/nvidia-361/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007f852c25c000)
    libogg.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0 (0x00007f852c053000)
    libopencv_core.so.2.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4 (0x00007f852bbb6000)
    libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4 (0x00007f852b6bd000)
    libjasper.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so.1 (0x00007f852b466000)
    libIlmImf.so.6 => not found
    libHalf.so.6 => not found
    libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 (0x00007f852b176000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f852af22000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f852ac11000)
    libgstapp-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstapp-0.10.so.0 (0x00007f852aa04000)
    libgstvideo-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-0.10.so.0 (0x00007f852a7e6000)
    libv4l1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l1.so.0 (0x00007f852a5e0000)
    libavcodec.so.54 => not found
    libavformat.so.54 => not found
    libavutil.so.52 => not found
    libswscale.so.2 => not found
    libQtOpenGL.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtOpenGL.so.4 (0x00007f852a2dc000)
    libQtGui.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4 (0x00007f85295e8000)
    libQtTest.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtTest.so.4 (0x00007f85293c2000)
    libQtCore.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4 (0x00007f8528ece000)
    liblcms2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblcms2.so.2 (0x00007f8528c77000)
    libicudata.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55 (0x00007f85271bf000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f8526ede000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f8526c93000)
    libhogweed.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4 (0x00007f8526a60000)
    libnettle.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6 (0x00007f852682a000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007f85265a9000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f85261ef000)
    libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007f8525f89000)
    libidn.so.11 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11 (0x00007f8525d56000)
    libtasn1.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007f8525b43000)
    libsoxr.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsoxr.so.0 (0x00007f85258dd000)
    libnuma.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnuma.so.1 (0x00007f85256d2000)
    liborc-0.4.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liborc-0.4.so.0 (0x00007f8525451000)
    libpostproc-ffmpeg.so.53 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpostproc-ffmpeg.so.53 (0x00007f8525235000)
    libavresample-ffmpeg.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavresample-ffmpeg.so.2 (0x00007f8525012000)
    libzmq.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5 (0x00007f8524dac000)
    libfribidi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfribidi.so.0 (0x00007f8524b95000)
    libflite_cmu_us_awb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libflite_cmu_us_awb.so.1 (0x00007f852459f000)
    libflite_cmu_us_kal.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libflite_cmu_us_kal.so.1 (0x00007f852423c000)
    libflite_cmu_us_kal16.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libflite_cmu_us_kal16.so.1 (0x00007f8523c65000)
    libflite_cmu_us_rms.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libflite_cmu_us_rms.so.1 (0x00007f85235cc000)
    libflite_cmu_us_slt.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libflite_cmu_us_slt.so.1 (0x00007f8522fd6000)
    libflite.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libflite.so.1 (0x00007f8522da0000)
    libbs2b.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbs2b.so.0 (0x00007f8522b99000)
    libass.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libass.so.5 (0x00007f8522969000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f8522764000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f852255e000)
    libcdio.so.13 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcdio.so.13 (0x00007f8522339000)
    libpulse-simple.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse-simple.so.0 (0x00007f8522133000)
    libusb-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f8521f1b000)
    libjson-c.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjson-c.so.2 (0x00007f8521d0f000)
    libpulsecommon-8.0.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsecommon-8.0.so (0x00007f8521a95000)
    libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007f8521849000)
    libslang.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libslang.so.2 (0x00007f85214bc000)
    libncursesw.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.5 (0x00007f852128d000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f8521064000)
    libtbb.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so.2 (0x00007f8520e26000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f8520c22000)
    libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f8520a19000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f85207a9000)
    libgstbase-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbase-0.10.so.0 (0x00007f852054f000)
    libv4l2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l2.so.0 (0x00007f8520340000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f8520136000)
    libaudio.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaudio.so.2 (0x00007f851ff1c000)
    libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0x00007f851fd14000)
    libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0x00007f851fafa000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f851f8e5000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f851f613000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f851f3e3000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f851f1df000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f851efd4000)
    libsodium.so.18 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsodium.so.18 (0x00007f851ed75000)
    libflite_usenglish.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libflite_usenglish.so.1 (0x00007f851eb4c000)
    libflite_cmulex.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libflite_cmulex.so.1 (0x00007f851e8b6000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f851e658000)
    libudev.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 (0x00007f851e637000)
    libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007f851e5b2000)
    libwrap.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwrap.so.0 (0x00007f851e3a8000)
    libasyncns.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasyncns.so.0 (0x00007f851e1a1000)
    libv4lconvert.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4lconvert.so.0 (0x00007f851df27000)
    libXt.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6 (0x00007f851dcbd000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f851dab8000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f851d8b4000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f851d698000)
    libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007f851d473000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f851d250000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1
```

My sourced.list is

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
```

This problem also appears to effect opencv.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a directory to my path?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path)

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `lsb_release -a`

Comment: And the output of `apt-cache policy blender`

Comment: Very interesting. The current Wily version is 2.74+dfsg0-4build2 > http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=wily&searchon=names&keywords=blender
Xenial has 2.76.b+dfsg0-3build1

Comment: Might be because my system crashed while updating to 16.04 and never finished. I can finish the installation but then this question would go off topic?

Comment: Right, that's your problem. http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/b/blender/ has 2.74 and not 2.76 You have to finish your Xenial upgrade.

Comment: `apt-cache policy blender` gives the same output?

Comment: `libIlmImf.so` is part of the [`openexr` package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openexr) on which Blender should depend. The missing dependency is a packaging bug of the Blender package. This stuff can easily happen in beta releases of Ubuntu. Please [file a bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/blender). Bug reports especially against beta release packages are off topic on AU.

Comment: Shouldn't that be fixed by sudo apt-get install openexr. By the way I reinstalled my system with the official 16.04 release but the problem persists.

Comment: I have also updated my cache-policy ext.

Comment: I set up a xenial chroot but was unable to reproduce the problem. Can you try reinstalling?

Comment: I tried reinstalling the machine once before, the machine in question is a elitebook8570w.

Comment: @Thijser You tried reinstalling and got the same problem? BTW, note that to notify someone of a comment, put @ username in front.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I tried a reinstall over the old one which is not exactly the same as a clean install but does repair a lot of things.

Comment: @Thijser By a reinstall, I meant an install from scratch. I'm not sure what "a reinstall over the old one" means.

Comment: @FaheemMitha with ubuntu you can, if you select the same username and password, maintain you home folder when you reinstall ubuntu by selecting the same disk as an older ubuntu installation.

Comment: @Thijser Oh, so you just keep the home directory? That sounds harmless. So, did a re-installation not fix the problem then?

Comment: @FaheemMitha no that didn't resolve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For something unrelated to this I ran the opencv installation script https://github.com/jayrambhia/Install-OpenCV/blob/master/Ubuntu/2.4/opencv2_4_9.sh and afterwards blender suddenly started working, perhaps there is some dependency that is not properly stated.

Of course it's also possible that this was solved by a more recent ubuntu update.

Comment: If anyone figures out exactly which of these things fixed my issue, you can have the bounty.

Comment: Installing worked fine. Even tried opencv2_4_10.sh. But this didn't install 'libIlmImf.so.6' for me.

Comment: @MadMike did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @FightFireWithFire Sorry no news: I have since since looked at it again.

Answer (score 4):

I just had this issue, `libIlmImf` is part of the `libopenexr` package. To fix this:

`$ sudo apt-get install libopenexr-dev`

I'm guessing OpenCV installs this package as part of the installation, hence the top answer.

Comment: I had to install `libopenexr22`

Answer (score 1):

I got same error, but with `libgif.so.7`

I solved that error with :

1. search the name of the package via http://packages.ubuntu.com/
2. and I get the name of package is `libgif7`
3. remove **that** package with `apt-get remove libgif7` (*this action will remove blender too*)
4. reinstall blender with `apt-get install blender`

Finally this worked for me.

Comment: In my case it was easier to solve this by simply reinstalling libgif7, since a bunch of other packages would be removed if I removed libgif7. Use sudo apt install --reinstall libgif7. Fixed blender for me without losing any other packages that could be dependencies elsewhere.